# I have a Grid view With Some Columns such as Event,Date(in dd-mm-yyyy format) , I want spilt the Grid Views rows on the basis of the date?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Eg :

Grid View contains data as:

```
Event                             Date
All India Chess                 14-03-2013
Karnataka Chess                 25-04-2013
Haryana Chess                   14-03-2013
```

And i Want the result as:

```
Event                                Date 
                 13(March)
All India Chess                 14-03-2013
Haryana Chess                   14-03-2013

                 13(April)
Karnataka Chess                 25-04-2013
```

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Havent tried anything yet..NO clue..